# On a laptop are voltage input and voltage rating on a battery the same thing?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery

I need to replace the battery in my Samsung Notebook model #XE501C13-S02US. The label indicates input as 12V. When I shop for a battery for this model they all list a rating of 7.6V. I suspect we're talking apples and oranges here - but not sure. Is the 12V an input rating from the charger into the battery and the 7.6V rating the output of the battery? If so, how can I be sure they are compatible?

Comment: In short… no. "Input" is going to be either 120 or 240V. Output is 'low numbers' You must have all numbers matching,  right the way through. Go to a retail store and ask an assistant, before you make something go bang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The label input is the laptop side of the voltage specification for the external AC Adapter.

The input of from the external adapter will go through a voltage regulator to ensure the correct battery charge voltage (not very likely on the exterior label).

The battery voltage is the inside DC voltage of the battery itself.

Two different things.

Make certain the battery is a direct (size, voltage and AMP-Hour) replacement either from Samsung or a known 3rd party replacement (I have successfully used Dr Battery Amazon).